# Передать файл в input value по клику

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.
Я очень слабенький в JS, по этому заранее извиняюсь за глупый вопрос.

Есть функция, которая, по нажатию на `<a id="save">SAVE</a>` даёт на скачивание файл.

```
Recorder.setupDownload = function(blob, filename){
    var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
    var link = document.getElementById("save");
    link.href = url;
    link.download = filename || 'output.wav';
}
```

Сейчас же нужно, чтобы этот файл сохранился при помощи простой формы, для последующей обработки файла бэкендом.

```
<form method="POST" action="save" id="formsave" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="inputwav" type=file name=file>
</form>
```

Делал так:

```
Recorder.setupDownload = function(blob, filename){
    var form = getElementById("formsave")
    var input = getElementById("inputwav")
    var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
    input.value = url;
    form.submit();
}
```

Браузер возвращает ошибку : `SecurityError: The operation is insecure.`

Ситуация в том, что до сохранения, файла не существует.
Никак не понимаю, как зацепить этот файл.

JavaScript код, естественно, не мой, иначе бы я не стал задавать такого вопроса :)

[Пример](https://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html) того, где этот код используется

[Файл](http://view-source:https://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/js/recorderjs/recorder.js), с этой функцией.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, нельзя скриптом задать value у input с типом file. Это запрещает политика безопасности браузера

Comment: @Talleyran, да, кажется что именно так и есть. 

Буду искать другие варианты, спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Свойство value у input типа file доступно только для чтения из соображений безопасности. Скриптом его изменить нельзя https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_fileupload_value.asp